# What is the main difference in between PGNAA and PINS?

Tags: spectroscopy, radioactivity, neutrons

I understand that both use a neutron emitter to trigger the material being analyzed to emit gamma radiation which is then analyzed to determine the material, but what is the exact difference between these methods? Is it only that PINS is portable, but PGNAA is not?

[PGNAS (Prompt Gamma Neutron Activation Analysis)](https://www.frontier-cf252.com/pgnaa/) and
[PINS (Portable Isotopic Neutron Spectroscopy)](https://www.frontier-cf252.com/portable-isotopic-neutron-spectroscopy/)

Comment: Is there a difference?